# PHP Возврат набранной строки после нажатия кнопки submit

Tags: php

подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли возможность реализовать что то вроде этого?

echo 'Text input type="datetime-local" name="Date" value="тут скобка для кода php if(isset($_GET['date'])) { echo $_GET['date']; } " required закрывает php код';

Суть в том что после нажатия на submit, набранная дата/текст не скидывался, а оставался. Понимаю что пихаю php в php, но это лишь грубый пример.
Реализовать это надо именно в php через echo...
Спасибо большое

Comment: в html это реализуют так
<input type="text" name="searchterms" value="<?php echo searchform(); ?>" />

Comment: Используй сессии http://php.net/manual/ru/session.examples.basic.php

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ,
В правильном ли направлении иду?
        session_start();
        if (!isset($_SESSION['date_lalala'])) {
            $_SESSION['date_lalala'] = $date_lalala;
        }

Comment: + забыл сказать, что переменная date ранее уже передана в _GET

Comment: Да. Возможна проблема с обновлением данных. В вашем примере вы используете проверку на пустоту `if (!isset($_SESSION['date_lalala']))` если после первого обновления данные записались, то последующие, измененные могут не записаться т.к сессия под этим именем уже имеет данные. Тестируйте.

Comment: как можно тогда запихать значение даты из гет массива и поместить его в value
Простите за детские вопросы
плохо еще знаю синтаксис...

Comment: Передать данные из сессии в js `document.getElementsByClassName('set_fondness')[0].value = 10;`

Comment: https://habr.com/sandbox/76960/ от этого отталкивайся

Comment: Вспомнил что можно еще сделать так `<input type = "text" value = "<?php echo 10; ?>">`

Answer (score 0):

Код формы:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" value="<?=isset($_GET['input']) ? $_GET['input'] : ""?>" name="input">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Надеюсь я верно понял

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем решил проблему так, объявил переменную $date = $_GET[date] до функции
в самой функции объявил global $date;
и далее в input value всунул конкатом переменную $date
Всем большое спасибо.
Вопрос оставлю, т.к. может новичкам как мне пригодиться.